# Tcl Regexp confusion

Tags: regex, tcl

I have the following code in a tcl script

```
$a_list - {Hello1.my.name.is.not.adam.go.away, 
           Hello2.my.name.is.not.adam,
           Hello3.my.name.is.not.adam.leave.me}

foreach a $a_list {if {[regexp adam [regsub {.*\.} $a {}]] == 1} {puts $a} }
```

My understanding is that this looks for the string adam in  $a_list and it matches when adam is the last string.
For example

```
Hello1.my.name.is.not.adam.go.away  ---> NO MATCH
Hello2.my.name.is.not.adam          ---> MATCH
Hello3.my.name.is.not.adam.leave.me ---> NO MATCH
```

The problem I am facing is that I want to match with adam and then strip away everything away after including adam itself.
For example

```
Hello1.my.name.is.not.adam.go.away  ---> MATCH
Hello2.my.name.is.not.adam          ---> MATCH
Hello3.my.name.is.not.adam.leave.me ---> MATCH
```

In all cases above, it should change the string to

```
Hello1.my.name.is.not  ---> MATCH
Hello2.my.name.is.not  ---> MATCH
Hello3.my.name.is.not  ---> MATCH
```

Your help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1 :**

With simple `string` commands, we can get the desired result.

```
set input {Hello1.my.name.is.not.adam.go.away, Hello2.my.name.is.not.adam, Hello3.my.name.is.not.adam.leave.me noobuntu dinesh}
foreach elem $input {
    # Getting the index of the word 'adam' in each element 
    set idx [string first "adam" $elem]
    # If the word is not  available, then 'idx' will have the value as '-1'
    if {$idx!=-1} {
        # string range will give the substring for the given indices
        puts "->[string range $elem 0 [expr {$idx-1}]]"
    }
}
```

will give output as follows,

```
->Hello1.my.name.is.not.
->Hello2.my.name.is.not.
->Hello3.my.name.is.not.
```

**Method 2:**

If you are interested only with regex patterns, then it can tweaked by `regsub` command as

```
set input {Hello1.my.name.is.not.adam.go.away, Hello2.my.name.is.not.adam, Hello3.my.name.is.not.adam.leave.me noobuntu dinesh}
foreach elem $input {
    if {[regsub {(.*?)adam.*$} $elem {\1} result]} {
        puts "->$result"
    }
}
```

will produce output as

```
->Hello1.my.name.is.not.
->Hello2.my.name.is.not.
->Hello3.my.name.is.not.
```

Reference : [string](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/string.htm), [regsub](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regsub.htm)

Comment: `regsub {adam.*} $elem {} result` should be much simpler IMO.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach to strip the word `adam` and everything after it in each element of a list, you use a simple `regsub` and `lmap`:

```
% lmap s $a_list {regsub {\madam\M.*} $s ""}
Hello1.my.name.is.not. Hello2.my.name.is.not. Hello3.my.name.is.not.
```

The `\m` only matches at the start of a word, and the `\M` only matches at the end of a word. It works because if the word *isn't* there, `regsub` does nothing.

---

Using Tcl 8.5? You won't have `lmap`, and will need to do this instead:

```
set result {}
foreach s $a_list {
    lappend result [regsub {\madam\M.*} $s ""]
}
# The altered list is now in $result
```